# CHOSEN JQuery plugin, does anyone know if it can be made to do a 'contains' search?

Tags: jquery-plugins

I finally got this plugin to work with IE9 in compatibility mode only to realize that its only filtering by 'starts with' ... has anyone implemented or knows how to make this thing work with a 'contains' search instead?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Chosen now supports this directly as an option:

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen({ search_contains: true });
```

Comment: I noticed if there is a value `My-Name`, and I search for `Na`, it doesn't yield any result. Any idea how to allow to search hyphenated name?

Answer (score 1):

From 'pfiller' on the Chosen issues forum:

Chosen doesn't support it by default, but it is a relatively minor change. Just remove the `^` from the following line:

```
regex = new RegExp('^' + searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), 'i')
```

Should look like this now:

```
regex = new RegExp(searchText.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), 'i')
```